# Extract All occurrences (not just the first one) matching a regex in a Google sheets cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to extract all occurrences matching a regex from a Google Sheets cell.

Example of a cell content in D5:

> Genauer zu reden, sie sind gegeben sozusagen als Einbettungen in konkreten psychischen Erlebnissen, die in der Funktion der Bedeutungsintention oder Bedeutungserfüllung (in letzterer Hinsicht als illustrierende oder evidentmachende Anschauung) zu gewissen sprachlichen Ausdrücken gehören und mit ihnen eine phänomenologische Einheit bilden

`REGEXEXTRACT(D5; "\w+edeut\w+")` only returns the first match, i.e. *Bedeutungsintention*.

I need all of them. In this case, *Bedeutungsintention* and *Bedeutungserfüllung*

Thanks !

Comment: How about using /g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To process D2:D with an array formula, try the following formula in, say, E2 (or the second cell of any otherwise empty range of columns wide enough to accommodate the maximum number of extractions that any one row may produce):

`=ArrayFormula(IF(D2:D="",,SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(SPLIT(D2:D," "),"[A-Za-zäÄöÖüÜß]+edeut[A-Za-zäÄöÖüÜß]+"))),,COLUMNS(SPLIT(D2:D," "))))," ",0,1)))`

This takes advantage of a quirk with `QUERY` whereby any number of header columns can be selected, not just 0 or 1. If we `TRANSPOSE` all data, then run a `QUERY` for nothing but headers, requesting as many headers as max results per transposed row, and then `TRANSPOSE` back to the original orientation, we get all matching results in one string. Then we can `SPLIT` that composite header string into separate cells by row.

Comment: It works beautifully and uses a regex. Where can I read a bit more about this quirk ? I just want to understand the formula completely.

Comment: Glad it works as you had hoped, Antoine. If you would, please take a moment to mark the post as "Best Answer." This alerts the community here that the issue has been fully resolved; and it helps future site visitors quickly find the most relevant solutions. Regarding the quirk with QUERY, it is not an officially documented feature; so there is no one place I know of where you can learn a lot more about it. It's just an "insider secret."

Answer (score 2):

All of these examples can be seen in [this shared file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ekEf6pvz63NGD0M6kTgGYoF-Vbr3yli54IqOVRKszpE/edit#gid=0)

### Formula Solution

`=Filter(split(textjoin(" ",true,D5:D)," "),find("edeut",split(textjoin(" ",true,D5:D)," "),1)>0)`

This is probably the easiest as it uses standard sheet functionality. It splits (converts to an array) the text based on a space `' '` separator. It then filters on any words that contain the specified text. From there you can use other sheet functionality to manipulate the text (`transpose`, `unique`, `substitute` out other characters such as periods)

Using the `textjoin` function will allow for this to be applied to multiple cells.

### Custom Function Solution

This is basically doing the same as the first option but using app scripts. It might provide more flexibility.

```
 /**
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */

/**
 * Finds instances of value
 * 
 * @param {range} theCells the Cell(s) with a value.
 * @param {string} theTextToSearch Text to find.
 * @param {string} theSplitter Text to split values
 * @return the results split by the thesplitter.
 * @customfunction
 */

function returnSomeText(theCells, theTextToSearch, theSplitter) {
  var allValues = theCells;
  if (Array.isArray(allValues)){
    allValues = allValues.join(" ");
  }

  var theArray = allValues.split(" ");
  var allResults =[];
  for(var i= 0;i<theArray.length;i++){
    if(theArray[i].search(theTextToSearch)>0){
      allResults.push(theArray[i]);
    }
  }
  return allResults.join(theSplitter);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works great on a single cell, but it does not scale well, so I'm receiving some " Exceeded maximum execution time (línia 0)." errors. Could I apply it to a range in a single function call, say =returnSomeText(D2:D1002;"edeut";"
") for example ? Best !

Comment: @AntoineBrunel, I updated the code and the googlesheets. Hopefully that works. As a reminder, subsequent questions that were not in the original question are frowned upon on SO. So assuming this doesn't brea, I'd be most grateful if you clicked the `accept` button. Thanks!

Comment: Also, if you use the googleSheets function `TextJoin` to the list of cells embedded in the function, the original would work fine.